# Show Don't Tell = nervous

Tags: writing

How would you use "Show Don't Tell" [imagery](http://www.newsu.org/course_files/nwsu_headlinesThatWork10a/pdf/specificity-imagery.pdf) to portray a person who is watching something (an encounter) that makes him nervous? All I can think of is: I could feel my body begin to sweat.

Comment: Welcome.  I'm not sure what you mean by using show and tell with sweating. Do you mean you will run until you get sweaty and then show that to people? In what way is the sentence, "I could feel my body begin to sweat." an example of show and tell. Please explain -- thanks.

Comment: If you're asking about how nervousness can manifest itself, *biting your nails*, or *chewing your fingernails* are widely thought of as evidence. Whether that's physiologically true, I have no idea (likewise with sweating, by the way).

Comment: J. Doe - Here is a suggestion:  When you say, 'portray a person who is watching something' -- that is extremely vague. Please can you give a real example, e.g. " a person is watching a horror movie on television and he begins to ___".  A specific example often helps us much more than a general statement.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "Show don't tell" is a style of writing where an action is described instead of simply specified. E.g.: "He was tired." vs "His frame slouched forward, every step taking its toll."

Answer (score 1):

"I broke into a sweat.  My heart pounded, and my hand began to feel clammy against my bouncing knee.  I began to pace back and forth, stomping my feet impatiently at each end of the room.  The very act of watching was hurting my eyes, and my heart was still threatening to burst forth from my ribcage."

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

> **have sweat beading/[breaking out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could+feel+sweat+breaking+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20feel%20sweat%20breaking%20out%3B%2Cc0)
>   on one's forehead**, as in
>
> *I was so nervous I thought I was gonna throw up again. I could feel sweat beading on my forehead as I walked around the corner*. [All Along
>   The
>   Watchtower](http://www.teenink.com/fiction/realistic_fiction/article/547167/All-Along-The-Watchtower/)

Here are a couple more suggestions you might find interesting on how to express nervousness in writing:

> **have one's heart in one's mouth (or *throat*)**
>
> : if someone's heart is in their mouth, they feel extremely nervous;
>   *My heart was in my mouth as I walked onto the stage*. [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/heart+is+in+mouth)
>
> *I could feel my heart in my throat as Tracy's blue Geo sliced through the eerie darkness of Martin's street*. [Class Dismissed: 75
>   Outrageous, Mind-Expanding College
>   Exploits](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=WQ_RPhO-j6IC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=%22could+feel+my+heart+in+my+throat+as%22&source=bl&ots=agMXipnfdF&sig=mqqqNkg-5QOsi6WRaYSMwek3-bg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAWoVChMIqq6Lr4jMyAIVwr0aCh2dtw-V#v=onepage&q=%22could%20feel%20my%20heart%20in%20my%20throat%20as%22&f=false)
>
> [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heart+was+in+my+mouth%2Cheart+was+in+my+throat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheart%20was%20in%20my%20mouth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheart%20was%20in%20my%20throat%3B%2Cc0)
>
> **have one's heart pounding (or *pulse racing*)**, as in:
>
> *My heart was pounding as I watched her pull into the parking lot. Just
>   knowing that she and my father were in the same town was making me
>   want to go run and bury my head in a pillow*. [A More Perfect Union:
>   How I Survived the Happiest Day of My
>   Life](https://books.google.fr/books?id=vlwix-2zvvEC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=%22my+heart+was+pounding+as+i+watched%22&source=bl&ots=n3apP-Nbtc&sig=8zdC6LkjwZGLHSFpUOw58LMOS7U&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwB2oVChMIvLLgjIDMyAIVx9gaCh25zABO#v=onepage&q=%22my%20heart%20was%20pounding%20as%20i%20watched%22&f=false)
>
> [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel+my+heart+racing+as%2Cfeel+my+heart+pounding+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeel%20my%20heart%20racing%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeel%20my%20heart%20pounding%20as%3B%2Cc0)
>
> **butterflies in one's stomach**
>
> : a nervous feeling in one's stomach. (*Typically*: get ~; have ~; give
>   someone~.) *Whenever I have to speak in public, I get butterflies in
>   my stomach*. *She always has butterflies in her stomach before a
>   test*. *It was not frightening enough to give me butterflies in my
>   stomach, but it made me a little apprehensive*. [McGraw-Hill
>   Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal
>   Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/butterflies+in+stomach)
>
> *One day in the spring of 1999 Molly called to say she had a final version for me to come in and watch. I could feel butterflies in my
>   stomach as I made my way to the edit suite that afternoon. I kept
>   telling myself it would be OK.* [Just For The
>   Record](https://books.google.fr/books?id=UDj-vPnf-CgC&pg=PA72&dq=%22could+feel+butterflies+in+my+stomach+as%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIz6CFjJrMyAIVAr8aCh3sfwU1#v=onepage&q=%22could%20feel%20butterflies%20in%20my%20stomach%20as%22&f=false)
>
> [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could+feel+butterflies+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20feel%20butterflies%20in%3B%2Cc0)